# Avoiding an assignment in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I discovered `.andSelf()`, and I want to do something similar. Essentially, calling `.filter()` on a jQuery object will not modify the jQuery object. To modify it I have to do

```
$myElement = $myElement.filter(mySelector);
```

I don't really like that syntax. Is it possible to do something like:

```
$myElement.filter(mySelector).applyFilterToSelf();
```

Comment: That's unlikely to be possible. Most functions return a *new* jQuery object. `$myElement` can only refer to it if you assign it.

Comment: So how does `.addSelf()` work?

Comment: You can always look at the source. But `addSelf()` is doing the same, it *returns* a new jQuery object, which includes the elements from the previous step and then you call further methods on it...

Comment: Sounds like an unsuccessful attempt at premature micro-optimisation.